# How to escape word from date format angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find a way to escape word from date format in angular and show result as: `2016-12-23 23:59 GMT`. When I'm using next code

```
'date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm":"GMT"'
```

The angular shows date without any problem, but without word GMT. However I'm trying to pass a word "GMT" and escape it,

```
'date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm":"GMT" \"GMT\"'
```

I'm getting an syntax error.

This date format I'm using as cellFilter for my [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering) and setting from controller. [This is plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vrxf9GKfsqUe5j6hXRcu?p=preview) with my problem

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass the escape string into your format date string, like this:

```
cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm \'GMT\'":"GMT"'
```

The result: http://plnkr.co/edit/0FbYfjehnNo26Fw8wKva?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you not just append it?

```
{{'date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm":"GMT"'}} GMT
```

Comment: No I cannot, I'm setting this from controller as cellFilter for my ui-grid

Comment: Will you post more of that code? It will be easier to answer your question with more context.

Comment: antonyboom Are you going to make it where it can be filterable by other timezones or will it always be GMT?

Comment: ^ this is good question... You can also prepare data in controller before displaying it on view. There you can build "string" that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make you own custom filter, that accepts date and format it to a desired dispaly format with maybe moment.js or etc...

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot use third party library

Comment: You don't need a third party library to make a custom filter. That's just regular angular. Probably a good way to go.